# Flutter SQFLite cannot add record in 2nd table

Tags: flutter, sqflite

I am creating 2 tables(not related to each other) in SQFLite in the same database.

In each table, I want to use a separate class.

Two tables are created, but, in the second table, no records are added.

The first table adds a new record no problem.

Issue: A new record is not added in the 2nd table.

Model Class:

```
class ThemeFields {
  static final List<String> values = [id, ThemeLight];
  static final String id = '_id'; // SQL convention
  static final String ThemeLight = 'isThemeLight';
}

class myTheme {
  late final int? id;
  late int isThemeLight=0;
  myTheme({this.id,required this.isThemeLight});
  myTheme copy({int? id,int? isThemeLight}) => myTheme(id: id ?? this.id,isThemeLight: isThemeLight ?? this.isThemeLight);
  Map<String, Object?> toJson() => {ThemeFields.id: id,ThemeFields.ThemeLight: isThemeLight};
  static myTheme fromJson(Map<String, Object?> json) => myTheme(id: json[ThemeFields.id] as int?,isThemeLight: json[ThemeFields.ThemeLight] as int);
}
```

Database Operations Class - partial code:

```
Future _createDB(Database db, int version) async {
    var idType = 'INTEGER PRIMARY KEY AUTOINCREMENT';
    var textType = 'TEXT NOT NULL';
    await db.execute('''CREATE TABLE $myTable (
    ${TaskFields.id} $idType,
    ${TaskFields.myText} $textType,
    )''');
    await db.execute('CREATE TABLE myTheme(userId INTEGER PRIMARY KEY, isThemeLight TEXT NOT NULL)');
  }
```

Here - I am saving a record from class Phila - this code works fine:

```
Future<phila> create(Phila phila) async {
    final db = await instance.dataBase;
    final id = await db.insert(myTable, phila.toJson());
    return phila.copy(id: id);
}
```

Here - I want to save dark/light theme flag into separate table in the same database - this code does not work - no record is inserted into the table:

```
Future<myTheme> createTheme(myTheme theme) async {
    final db = await instance.dataBase;
    final id = await db.insert(myThemeTable, theme.toJson());
    return theme.copy(id: id);
  }
```

Save Theme statement:

```
saveTheme(){
    setState(() {
      DBHelper.instance.createTheme(myTheme(id: myindex,isThemeLight: 0));
    });
  }
```

This is showstopper critical issue. Please help.

Thank You

Comment: My advice to you would be to use shared preferences, not sql, for simple key-value data. And could it be a problem with your model class? Can you take a look at the model class?

Comment: I copied the model Class above. I don't want to use SharedPreferences b/c it significantly increases the size of the APK. Thank You

Comment: Is there any error catch in debugger or try catch thrown error

Comment: Hello! No errors are generated. I really need help on this issue. Thank You.

Answer (score 0):

Hard to know what is going wrong without more information. One issue I see is that you are setting `_id` to null in `MyTheme.toJson`. Can you try the following:

- enable [experimental logging](https://github.com/tekartik/sqflite/blob/master/sqflite/doc/dev_tips.md#try-the-experimental-logger):
  `databaseFactory = databaseFactory.debugQuickLoggerWrapper();`
- Fix to json to not set the id when null:

```
Map<String, Object?> toJson() => {if (id != null) ThemeFields.id: id,ThemeFields.ThemeLight: isThemeLight};
```